# What minimum'allows' should be used in iptables rules?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, iptables

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server which has two Ethernet ports: eth0 directly connects with a custom camera and eth1 connects via LAN cable to a wireless router.

I had been developing a web application when a contractor asked me to enable SSH that he could install yet-another-application.  Within a few seconds I found in the log two probes from China! I naively enabled UFW.  At that point I could no longer connect to the server through the LAN (although the server and the other computers could connect to the internet) and I immediately removed SSH.  Since then I disabled UFW, decided to use port xxx0 (security by obscurity), and reinstalled SSH.  I tested both my server and SSH from the LAN and they both work.

I'm a LINUX user not a system administer - and there's a lot to learn!

My question again is: What minimum services do I need for a system with a server and router?  Is this enough? (I expect to attach a network time server to the LAN later.) A reply to someone's post implies that the router may need:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3/4 -j ACCEPT
```

Have I missed anything else?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Dec 22 09:54:46 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [16:1431]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxx0 -j ACCEPT  # SSH
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxx5 -j ACCEPT  # WWW
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport xxx6 -j ACCEPT  # Web Socket
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport xxx8 -j ACCEPT  # camera
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT            # DNS
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p icmp -m limit --limit 10/sec -j ACCEPT # LOCAL DEBUGGING - REMOVE?
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Comment: `I found in the log two probes from China` - You are somewhat over-reacting to being probed.  If you are connected to the Internet, you will be probed, even if waste your time by using obscure ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICMP 3,4 are related to [PMTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery), without these some clients won't be able to connect reliably (for example ones using PPP lines to connect to Internet). The rest seems reasonable to start with.

Obscurity is ok (at some extent), but You can limit **incoming adresses** on iptables too (eg. make a list of allowed ssh client IPs), so there will be no reason to hide from China :) `ipset` may be usefull if these lists become large.

OUTPUT chain may be restricted also. If it is server-only, and *when* it will be hacked, these restrictions *may* help a bit (it may prevent installed malware calling home).